# How to speed up (parallelize) a grouped row-wise rolling mean calculation?

Tags: python, pandas, dask, swifter, pandarallel

I am calculating a grouped row-wise moving average on a large data set. However, the process takes a too long time on a single thread. How can I efficiently speed up the process?

Please find a reproducible example below:

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'id': range(2),
                   'group_id': range(2),
                   'Date_1_F1': [1,2], 
                   'Date_2_F1': [2,4], 
                   'Date_3_F1': [3, 6],
                   'Date_4_F1': [4,8], 
                   'Date_1_F2': [2,11], 
                   'Date_2_F2': [6, 13], 
                   'Date_3-F2': [10, 15],
                   'Date_4_F2': [14, 17]})
dataframe

   id  group_id  Date_1_F1  ...  Date_2_F2  Date_3-F2  Date_4_F2
0   0         0          1  ...          6         10         14
1   1         1          2  ...         13         15         17
```

I have a function that returns the (row-wise) smoothed version of the dataset.

```
def smooth_ts(dataframe, ma_parameter = 2):

    dataframe = (dataframe
                 .set_index(["id", "group_id"])
                 .groupby(lambda x: x.split("_")[-1], axis = 1, group_keys=False)
                 .apply(lambda x: x.rolling(ma_parameter, axis = 1)
                        .mean()
                        .dropna(axis=1, how='all')))
    
    dataframe.reset_index(inplace = True)
    
    return dataframe

smoothed_df = smooth_ts(dataframe)
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could (1) melt your data frame using `pd.melt`, (2) create your grouping variable, (3) sort and group it aggregated by  `rolling.mean(2)`. Then you can use `df.pivot` to display the required data. In this approach, there is an apply method that can be parallelized using `swifter`. Here is an example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import swifter

dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'id': range(2),
                   'group_id': range(2),
                   'Date_1_F1': [1,2], 
                   'Date_2_F1': [2,4], 
                   'Date_3_F1': [3, 6],
                   'Date_4_F1': [4,8], 
                   'Date_1_F2': [2,11], 
                   'Date_2_F2': [6, 13], 
                   'Date_3-F2': [10, 15],
                   'Date_4_F2': [14, 17]})

df_melted = pd.melt(dataframe, id_vars=['id', 'group_id'])
# Use next line if you want to parallelize the apply method 
# df_melted['groups'] = df_melted['variable'].str.split('_').swifter.apply(lambda v: v[-1])
df_melted['groups'] = df_melted['variable'].str.split('_').apply(lambda v: v[-1])

df_melted = df_melted.sort_values(['id', 'group_id', 'groups'])

df_tmp = df_melted.copy()
df_tmp['rolling_val'] = df_tmp.groupby(['id', 'group_id', 'groups'])['value'].rolling(2).mean().values
df_tmp.pivot(index=['id', 'group_id'], columns='variable', values='rolling_val').dropna(axis=1).reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

If you want to stick to your approach, you can accelerate it using the `Pool` object from the `multiprocessing` library, which parallelizes the mapping of a function to an iterator.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool


dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'id': range(2),
                   'group_id': range(2),
                   'Date_1_F1': [1,2], 
                   'Date_2_F1': [2,4], 
                   'Date_3_F1': [3, 6],
                   'Date_4_F1': [4,8], 
                   'Date_1_F2': [2,11], 
                   'Date_2_F2': [6, 13], 
                   'Date_3-F2': [10, 15],
                   'Date_4_F2': [14, 17]})
dataframe

def smooth_ts(dataframe, ma_parameter = 2):

    dataframe = (dataframe
                 .set_index(["id", "group_id"])
                 .groupby(lambda x: x.split("_")[-1], axis = 1, group_keys=False)
                 .apply(lambda x: x.rolling(ma_parameter, axis = 1)
                        .mean()
                        .dropna(axis=1, how='all')))
    
    dataframe.reset_index(inplace = True)
    
    return dataframe

id_chunks = np.array_split(dataframe.id.unique(), 2) # 2 : number of splits => corresponds to number of chunks
df_chunks = [dataframe[dataframe['id'].isin(i)] for i in id_chunks] # list containing chunked data frames
with Pool(2) as p: dfs_chunks = p.map(smooth_ts, df_chunks) # applies function smooth_ts to list of data frames, use two processors as dfs_chunks only contain two data frames. For more chunks, number of processors can be increased
pd.concat(dfs_chunks).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Hi @ko3, thank you. Do you have any idea which will be more efficient? Does it only depend on the number of columns?

Comment: It depends (on your machine, number of processors, rows, etc.). I would try both and compare them in terms of run times. I would do that for you but I don't have your data. If possible, add `.swifter` before the `.apply` method (see comment). Maybe there is even a way to get rid-off the `apply` method..

Comment: Thanks, @ko3. The data set has 4 million rows and ~20 columns with 2 groups. The computer has 20 cores. I will give it a try!